# Create file and save in user selected directory in android app

Tags: java, android

I want to give the user the opportunity to select a folder where to save the created file. I implemented the first step, but there were problems saving the file - I don’t know how to do it

Initially I have a variable for the URI:
`private Uri uri;`

I have method on click button:

```
selectPathForStore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFolderDialog(v);
            }
        });
```

The methods are called accordingly:

```
public void openFolderDialog(View view) {
        openFolder();
    }
public void openFolder(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                uri = intent.getData(); //here we save the path into an existing variable
                saveButton.setEnabled(true); //after setting the path, enable the save button
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You instantiate a DocumentFile instance for the obtained uri and then use its createFile() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have config the permission layers properly in your application manifest

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: One does not need any permission for what OP wants.